# Remove " " from key string in a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

Here's my dictionary:

```
Birthdate = "01-01-0001";
CareerField = 3;
Gender = 2;
"Interests[0].UserProfileId" = 19594;
"Interests[0].UserSurveyId" = 1;
SocialStatus = 2;
Studies = 3;
```

But I want the Interests key to be without "".Like that:

```
Birthdate = "01-01-0001";
CareerField = 3;
Gender = 2;
Interests[0].UserProfileId = 19594;
Interests[0].UserSurveyId = 1;
SocialStatus = 2;
Studies = 3;
```

UPDATE:
Interests i must send them like array.

```
[dict setObject:self.birthdayDate forKey:@"Birthdate"]
[dict setObject:@(self.occupationPickerRow + 1) forKey:@"CareerField"];

for (int i = 0; i < [interestsArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *stringSurveyId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@", @"Interests[", indexCount, @"].UserSurveyId"];
    NSString *stringUserProfileId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@", @"Interests[", indexCount, @"].UserProfileId"];

    [dict setObject:[interestsArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:stringSurveyId];
    [dict setObject:@([[[MZEngine sharedInstance] currentUserModel] userId]) forKey:stringUserProfileId];
    indexCount++;
}
```

Comment: Anyone can figured out?

Comment: Did you get this dictionary from any service?

Comment: I need this dictionary for a service.

Comment: Do you mean you want to send this dictionary as a parameter?

Comment: Key for a dictionary **has** to be a string. Or am i mistaken?

Comment: Yes you're right...It has to be a string, like all keys. But without "".

Comment: Yup! @Rikh is right key for dictionary has to be string. Not sure but may be you declared birthday,careerField as a variable. Is it?

Comment: I update my post.

Comment: Yes, birthday, career, etc I declared them as variables

Comment: Show the code for how you're determining the contents of the dictionary. You're almost certainly confusing its `description` with how it's actually represented internally. Those quote characters are only in the description, not the actual key.